# React.js Socket.io

Tags: javascript, sockets, reactjs, socket.io

I have a problem with socket.io (probably because I dont understand it properly).

I want to just make consistent request to server to get current number of players in queue(i think that socket is better than just setInterval).

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        self.getPlayersInQueue();
    });
}
```

In the getPlayersInQueue() i just make a fetch to server

```
return fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            return responseJson;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

If i do it without sockets just a normal request it works good.

Can someone tell me what am I missing? Maybe I dont really understand how sockets work?

PS: I dont know if its important but I`m making a request to an existing server online from localhost.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: What are you doing with the `responseJson` being returned from `getPlayersInQueue` in `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Im just getting the result of it and setting the players state. Am I doing the request good? This is how you should use sockets?